# Android Context menu from listsview

Tags: android, listview, menu

I am new to android development, and not very good at programming in general but, I am working on a tab layout that has a listview per tab.  Each tab has it's own java file. I am currently trying to add a context menu that when clicked (not long clicked) on an item in my listview, will bring up a menu so I can choose an option.  Right now it just shows a toast displaying the name of the item I clicked.  The listview options are currently added to the list via local string declaration, here is an example of on of my tabs:

```
public class AlbumTab extends ListActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      final String[] CDExplorer_tabs = new String[] {"Client Heirarchy", "Territory", "Sales Credit", "Admin", "General Search"};
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, CDExplorer_tabs));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
      {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) 
        {

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
    }
```

would I have to make another string array for each menu I want to popup and somehow connect it to the other string?  Or do if statements that decide on which menu to popup based on which listview item is clicked?

Comment: What kind of choices do you want to show on the Context Menu?

Comment: Each of the strings  (client hierarchy, territory, etc) will have multiple choices, I'm just looking for an example I can modify, like when if i click on client hierarchy, the menu is opened up, It will have choices to select that will take me to another page.  So if I click on Client hierarchy, I can choose from options like, firm, name, office location, etc.

Comment: From what I understand you need different options for each item in the list. Context Menu wouldn't be well suited for that.

Comment: Yes I need different options for each list item, what should I use, and how can I apply it?

Comment: If someone could tell me how to do a listview in a listview that would work too, Kind of like the default music player app on the droid.

Comment: Nvm, I ended up making a list open in a whole new window which works just as fine

Answer (score 0):

First, you if you want each part of the list to have a different menu, make a switch statement in your onItemClick() that depends on your position. `switch(position){ //cases and such`

Then what you might want to try instead of having a nested ListView is try doing an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Search for adding a list. And then implementing that for each position on your list. Then make sure that you implement another switch inside of the DialogInterface onClick function to call a function to do what you what it to do from the list.//Also make sure to alert.show();.

That would be my recommendation if you want to do it. However, if you want to do nested listviews, its more complicated but possible.

What you need to is implement a custom list adapter for you list. And create a view holder for each that holds a another listview. A good example for that is [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html).

That should pretty much do it. Mind you that if you decide to do the nested listviews it will be very crowded inside that listview.